# The negation of assertion

Tags: logic

Let  $(f_\alpha)_{\alpha \in [0,1]}\subset\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}, $ we assume the following assertion:

$$
\forall x\in \mathbb{R},\exists A\in\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}) (\text{ such that }x\in A):f_\alpha \text{ are constants on } A \text{ except for a finite number between them}
$$
The negation of this assertion is
$$
\exists x\in \mathbb{R},\forall  A\in\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}) (\text{ such that }x\in A) :\exists \alpha\in [0,1] : f_\alpha \text{ is not constants function on } A?
$$

Comment: $x$ does not appear anywhere after $\forall x \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: If for each $\alpha \in [0,1]$, $f_\alpha$ is a map from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$, then your first inclusion doesn’t make sense as a sequence of real maps is not included in $\mathbb R^{\mathbb R}$. Please clarify.

Comment: I corrected an error you can see it please $(x\in A)$